# Hardware reset screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-2, charging, power-on

[image]My Samsung Galaxy SII has not been used for a while, and whenever I try to plug it in to charge, it doesn't seem to start charging, and instead loops between the battery charging icon, and a screen with an image of the android icon. This screen has, in red writing, what appears to be a value for RST_STAT at the top of the screen (This is always 0x10000), and in larger text beside the android icon, the words 'Hardware reset' (without the quotes). Does anyone have any idea how I could get this phone working again?

Comment: Uh, what? I have never heard of this. At least you have good etiquette on question asking :) Is it possible we can get a picture of this screen? Trust me, it would help.

Comment: @Dan Brown I added a picture of the screen

Comment: Thank you. Never heard of AST_STAT before, but I think its a invalid warranty counter. Have you ever rooted, or installed a custom rom/recovery/bootloader/etc.?

Comment: Some digging has found [this link to a tomsguide.com post]( http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-2095103/samsung-galaxy-starting.html) AST and RST seem to be the same.

Comment: @Dan Brown The phone was rooted, and I had installed a custom rom on it. However, since I couldn't get google play services to work on the custom rom, I recovered to the stock rom (latest update). I unrooted the phone in order to use some apps which didn't allow rooting. It did work for about 6 months after that, at which point I got a new phone.

Comment: Also, the picture is a bit blurry, but it says RST_STAT, not AST.

Comment: ok :) the RST_STAT is essentially a knox counter. You will need to reflash the stock ROM (Hope you didn't delete it! You can probably find it on sammobile.com if you deleted it) and, well,  cross your fingers. You can flash by ODIN,  or kies (preferred)

Comment: @Dan Brown Unfortunately I can't do this as it is stuck in a bootloop

Comment: well, ODIN flashes are done through download mode, so hold power +vol down+ home (if you have a home button), then press up at the prompt. You need ODIN on a PC and the Stock ROM for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.**

I'm still not certain what the problem was, but my best guess is that the battery was completely dead. Anyway, I got a new battery, which completely solved the problem.